# How can I get the images in my navbar to shrink when the screen gets smaller

Tags: html, css, navbar

I want the images included in my navbar to automatically resize so the images stay next to each other and not on top of each other, if that makes sense. basically when testing how it would look on a phone the navbar takes up a good third of the screen.

This is my HTML

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">    
        <a id="logoHolder" class="navbar-brand">
            <img id="navbarIMG" src="/assets/navbar_logo.png">
        </a>
        <a id="cogfeedHolder" class="navbar-brand">
            <img id="cogfeedIMG" src="/assets/cogfeed_logo.png">
        </a>
        <a id="accountHolder" class="navbar-brand">
            <img id="accountIMG" src="assets/account_icon.png">
        </a>       
    </nav>
</body>
```

and this is my css

```
.navbar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(darkblue, blue, darkblue);
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#navbarIMG {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#cogfeedIMG {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#accountIMG {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
}

#logoHolder {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 342.4px;
    max-height: 102.29px;
}

#cogfeedHolder {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 339.2px;
    max-height: 74.35;
}

#accountHolder {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 136px;
    max-height: 118px;
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated I'm pretty crap at formatting stuff aha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it using an img-responsive class from bootstrap and removing the nav-brand classes. Then putting this in my stylesheet

```
.img-responsive {
    max-width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

edit the max-width to make it bigger or smaller and if you apply an id to the images you can set the width for individual images

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: flex` and `align-items: baseline` to your `.navbar` class. CSS flexbox is a great tool for various layouts along with CSS grid. You can learn more about it here: [Flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
.navbar {
background-image: linear-gradient(darkblue, blue, darkblue);
display: flex;
align-items: baseline;
```

}

Hope that helps!
[JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/p9zqcxnm/5/)

Comment: this hasn't worked. is it possible the issue is with my assets? they're pngs so should resize

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue with the actual images. Have you seen the attached fiddle? Is that the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: That is the behaviour I'm looking for. I'm using bootstrap which I forgot to mention I don't know if that would effect it